# Custom Error Page_Load is executed on each redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-error-pages

I added a custom Error page to my project. The problem is that each time I do a redirect to another page the code in the page_load of the error.aspx is executed.

In my project I make use of UpdatePanels and one masterpage.
All my pages use the masterpage incl the error page.
I even tried to use a error page which doesn't use my masterpage. And i still got the same problem.

In my web.config I have the following code:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Applicatie/Algemeen/Error.aspx" />
```

This is how I linked my error page(.aspx) with the masterpage:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Error.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.Applicatie.Algemeen.Error" %>
```

Is there any good reason on why this code is always executed.

---

I Tried to use the Application_Error in Global.asax.
It looks like the code in there is also triggered every time a navigate to a new page.
I realy don't know what causes this error when i try to debug en want to look who is the sender it returns Global.asax and when i dig even deeper i get this:
[Image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/861/errorkz.png)! (can't post images yet)

Comment: 1) Your code is not shown in the question

Comment: 2) if as you mentioned the master page includes the error page, of course the page_load is then always executed. Can you show us the way you include the error page in the master page?

Comment: it looks to me there is something erroneous in the pages you are trying to redirect to. Are your pages shown properly if swith off the custom errors?

Comment: "http://localhost:1042/favicon.ico" is missing which is cousing my errors. But i didn't even put a reference to that icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had an error in my application. Each time I loaded a page my browser couldn't find a favicon.
Because of that, i got an unhandeld error each time my browser loaded a new page. And thats why for some reason the Error pages code was runned.
Now that i added my own favicon all problems have been solved it's really strange that this can cause so much problems.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call ResponseRedirect(url) the current thread is aborted with the ThreadAbortException. Try to use ResponseRedirect(url, false)

Maybe the following link will be helpful for you: [Handling ThreadAbortException with Response.Redirect() : Best possible approaches](http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/handling-threadabortexception-with.html)

Comment: I have put a breakpoint on the page_load of the error page and even when i click on a link (with a navigationUrl) the code gets executed